# Objects sharing another object (Processing 3.3.7)

Tags: java, object, arraylist, processing

Hello Stack Overflow people :)

I'm a huge newbie when it comes to coding, and I've just ran into a problem that my brain just won't get over...

Before I start blabbering about this issue, I'll paste my code so as to give a little bit of context (sorry in advance if looking at it makes you wanna puke). The main focus of the issue is commented and should therefore be fairly visible :

### **Main**

```
ArrayList<Individual> individuals = new ArrayList<Individual>();

void setup()
{
  size(500,500);

  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    individuals.add(new Individual());
  }

  println(frameRate);
}

void draw()
{
  background(230);

  for(int i = 0; i < individuals.size(); i++)
  {
    individuals.get(i).move();

    individuals.get(i).increaseTimers();

    individuals.get(i).display();
  }
}
```

### **Individual**

```
class Individual
{
  float x;
  float y;
  int size = 5;

  Timer rdyBreed;        /* Here is the object that appears to be shared 
                            between individuals of the ArrayList */
  float breedRate;
  float breedLimit;

  Individual()
  {
    x = random(0, width);
    y = random(0, height);

    rdyBreed = new Timer("rdyBreed", 0);
    breedRate = random(.2, 3);
    breedLimit = random(10, 20);
  }

  void move()
  {
    int i = (int)random(0, 1.999);
    int j = (int)random(0, 1.999);

    if (i == 0)
    {
      x = x + 1;
    } else
    {
      x = x - 1;
    }

    if (j == 0)
    {
      y = y + 1;
    } else
    {
      y = y - 1;
    }

    checkWalls();
  }

  void checkWalls()
  {
    if (x < size/2)
    {
      x = width - size/2;
    }
    if (x > width - size/2)
    {
      x = size/2;
    }
    if (y < size/2)
    {
      y = width - size/2;
    }
    if (y > width - size/2)
    {
      y = size/2;
    }
  }

  void display()
  {
    noStroke();

    if (!rdyBreed.finished)
    {
      fill(255, 0, 0);
    } else
    {
      fill(0, 255, 0);
    }

    rect(x - size/2, y - size/2, size, size);
  }

  void increaseTimers()
  {
    updateBreedTimer();
  }

  void updateBreedTimer()
  {
    rdyBreed.increase(frameRate/1000);
    rdyBreed.checkLimit(breedLimit);
    rdyBreed.display(x, y);
  }
}
```

### **Timer**

```
class Timer
{
  float t;

  String name;

  boolean finished = false;

  Timer(String name, float t)
  {
    this.t = t;

    this.name = name;
  }

  void increase(float step)
  {
    if (!finished)
    {
      t = t + step;
    }
  }

  void checkLimit(float limit)
  {
    if (t >= limit)
    {
      t = 0;

      finished = true;
    }
  }

  void display(float x, float y)
  {
    textAlign(RIGHT);
    textSize(12);
    text(nf(t, 2, 1), x - 2, y - 2);
  }
}
```

Now that that's done, let's get to my question.

Basically, I'm trying to create some sort of a personal Conway's Game of Life, and I'm encountering a lot of issues right off the bat.

Now my idea when writing this piece of code was that every individual making up the small simulated "society" would have different timers and values for different life events, like mating to have children for example.

Problem is, I'm not a huge pro at object-oriented programming, and I'm therefore quite clueless as to why the objects are not having each their own Timer but both a reference to the same timer.

I would guess making an ArrayList of timers and using polymorphism to my advantage could make a change, but I'm not really certain of it or really how to do it so... yeah, I need help.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT : Here is a screenshot of the debugger. The values keep being the same with each iteration of the updates.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6hhx.png)

Comment: You’re saying that all the individuals are referencing the same Timer object?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add screenshots of the debugger but I will do it right now, as it makes it then clear that both are referencing to the same Timer object.

Comment: yes that would help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do not share the same timer, you create a `new Timer` object for each `Individual`.

```
class Individual {
    // ...
    Timer rdyBreed;

    Individual() {
        // ...
        rdyBreed = new Timer("rdyBreed", 0);
    //...
```

The only way they could be sharing the same `Timer` is if you were setting `rdyBreed` elsewhere, but since you don't want that I recommend making it `final`.

If you *did* want to share the same `Timer` instance across all individuals then you could declare it `static`.

Comment: Mmmh... That makes sense and that's what I would usually go with but in this case the debugger and the player seem to tell quite a different story. Have you tried running it ? The colors change in quite a weird fashion (compared to how they are supposed to change).

Comment: Being able to share the same timer across all of them would make this whole situation way easier, but the thing is that, as I want to create "individuals", I want them to have different rates of growth, learning and the such.

Comment: @Brynhildr Yep, I get that. Someone edited this answer thinking it'd be good to include explanation of `static` as well, and I figured "why not".  I don't think I have enough code to be able to run this, please supply everything. Missing `textAlign()` and such. Thanks.

Comment: I pasted everything :') You should be able to run it without a problem (supposedly). And I don't see where there is a missing `textAlign()` :c

Comment: where does `textAlign()` come from then? Nah, we're missing quite a bit..

Comment: Oh right, it's a built-in function in Processing ^^' Actually now that I think about it of course you're missing quite a bit if you're on something other than Processing, be it the `size()` or the `width` and `height`...

Comment: Hmm, I wont be downloading `Processing` sorry. Try making `rdyBreed` `final` just to see what happens.

Comment: It sadly didn't change a thing :c Welp, thanks for your help anyways, now I took the time to research and know what "final" is used for ;p

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think they reference the same ***Timer*** object? The values of ***t*** displayed in the debugger are going to be the same until one of them reaches the ***breedLimit*** and gets set to 0, because they're being initialized at the same time.
Try this and see that the values of ***t*** are [different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irB2h.png).

```
void setup() {
  size(500,500);
}

void mouseClicked() {
  individuals.add(new Individual());
}
```

I'd recommend setting the breakpoint somewhere around here:

```
t = 0;
finished = true;
```

Comment: Yep, I was ready to give up for the day about 15 minutes ago but I realized that about just before you posted it :') Thanks for your help anyways mate

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.